# AWS beanstalk fails installing pip requisites when downloading tensorflow==2.4.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a flask app that predicts whether a lung x-ray picture is COVID-19 positive using a Tensorflow CNN. It is running on python 3.7

This is my requirements.txt

```
tensorflow==2.4.0
Flask==1.1.2
Keras==2.4.3
numpy==1.19.5
Pillow==8.3.1
```

After deployment it, the environment's health status is labelled severe with a '502 Bad gateway' error.

These are the errors in the eb-engine.log

```
2021/08/23 10:47:40.676374 [INFO] Installing dependencies with requirements.txt by using Pip
2021/08/23 10:47:40.676387 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
2021/08/23 10:47:48.296114 [INFO] Collecting tensorflow==2.4.0
  Downloading tensorflow-2.4.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (394.8 MB)

2021/08/23 10:47:48.300932 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [InstallDependency]. Stop running the command. Error: fail to install dependencies with requirements.txt file with error Command /bin/sh -c /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt failed with error exit status 2. Stderr:ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 180, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
```

File "... repeats itself until here:

```
 File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/msgpack/fallback.py", line 896, in _pack
    return self._buffer.write(obj)
MemoryError
 

2021/08/23 10:47:48.300957 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2021/08/23 10:47:48.309000 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment failed to install application dependencies. The deployment failed.","timestamp":1629715668,"severity":"ERROR"},{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1629715668,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}

2021/08/23 10:47:48.312983 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: app-deploy

2021/08/23 12:34:34.689865 [INFO] Starting...
2021/08/23 12:34:34.689926 [INFO] Starting EBPlatform-PlatformEngine
2021/08/23 12:34:34.689965 [INFO] reading event message file
2021/08/23 12:34:34.690627 [INFO] no eb envtier info file found, skip loading env tier info.
2021/08/23 12:34:34.690716 [INFO] Engine received EB command cfn-hup-exec
```

why is AWS-Beanstalk failing to install Tensorflow?

Comment: MemoryError, just that.

Comment: does that mean that tensorflow is too large to download?

Comment: I suspect it's too large for this virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the environment EC2 capacity from t2.small to c5.xlarge and the problem was solved.
Your application needs more memory space.